# ssh keeps asking for passphrase with gcloud

Tags: macos, ssh, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to automate copying some local files from my mac (Mojave) into a GCP instance, using `gcloud compute scp`.

Works fine, but it keeps asking for the passphrase for the `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine` key `gcloud` created.

Is there anyway I can get rid of this so I can automate the process?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer?  I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

try `--quiet`:

From [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--quiet):

> `--quiet`, `-q`
>
> Disable all interactive prompts when running gcloud commands. If input
>   is required, defaults will be used, or an error will be raised.
>   Overrides the default core/disable_prompts property value for this
>   command invocation. Must be used at the beginning of commands. This is
>   equivalent to setting the environment variable
>   `CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS` to 1.

Comment: still asks for passphrase with `--quiet`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can *automate* entering the passphrase but you can surely remove the passphrase so it just uses your public and private keys stored in your local machine and does not ask for the passphrase *in addition* to using the keys

To do that, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74516400/1526703) answer. The jist is:

1. Remove the existing keys from `~/.ssh`
2. Try to reconnect with ssh. It'll recreate the keys since it won't find them and ask you if you want a passphrase. Don't create a passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by redirecting standard input from `/dev/null`:

```
gcloud compute scp delete.me myInstance:~/ < /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the ssh key to your ssh agent with

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine
```

See the man pages for `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` for details.